# ASP.NET MVC MultiSelectList selected item does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

I trying to use the `MultiSelectList` in ASP.NET MVC with selected items.

This is the backend code:

```
var listPoles = new List<long>();

foreach (var pole in employeePole.PolesList)
                listPoles.Add(pole.Id);

            ViewBag.poles = new MultiSelectList(GetPoles(), "Id", "Name", listPoles);
```

`GetPoles()` returns `IReadOnlyList`.

HTML code (view):

```
<select multiple="multiple" title="selecione..." class="form-control selectpicker" id="poles" asp-for="@Model.Poles" asp-items="@ViewBag.poles"></select>
```

In edit view (front-end) the select component does not load the selected items but I used the exactly same code (with different entity) in another CRUD in the same system and it works fine.

I tried to use a lot of different types of collection (enumerable, readonlylist, list, etc) to create the selected items list but nothing works

What can possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to debug if the list is filled with data.
2. Don't invoke GetPoles() method into MultiSelectList constructor, use a variable for this for clean code reasons
3. Check if GetPoles() does not contain asynchronous method
4. Viewbag can be cleaned after read. Try to use the model instead.

Comment: Hi Eryk Korzeniowski, thanks for your help but the problem persist. Follow my comments:

1. Yes! It's filled
2. Ok
3. I am using await for this
4. Viewbag is ok about it

Comment: 3. so if you using async method GetPoles() why you don't use await before invoking this method? There might be a problem with thread context losing. Try to do step 2 and await GetPoles(). Then use that variable into MultiSelectList.